# how do I set the combobox listindex to 0

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("generateReport").Object.ListIndex = 0
```

My ActiveX ComboBox is called "generateReport"
I want to reset the index to 0

I get an error saying

```
Run-time error 438.
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I am running my code from a Module.

Comment: what is the value of `ListCount`?

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("generateReport").ListIndex = 0`

Comment: Is you ComboBox really on the Active Sheet?

Comment: yes its really on the active sheet

Comment: I'm not sure  but I think that  index  in excel starts from 1 ?